# Can't see errors in own node module

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am relatively new to node (moving from PHP) and am encountering a problem that took me a while to figure out (meaning it took me a while to figure out what the problem was and now I have no idea how to fix it).

At the top of my node app (`server.js`), I have some requires. One of this requires my homemade api like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const v1 = require('./app/v1.js');
```

The v1 is just a function that returns the output to the api. However, there are many code problems with the v1 api as I have just wrote it and am testing it for the first time.

However, whenever there is a problem with the v1 function, node doesn't print it out and stop the program like it would if the problem were in the main `server.js` file. In fact (I am using nodemon so I don't have to restart each time), node just continues running like everything is moving perfectly smoothly. I understand why node would want to do this (they want people's app's to not be dependent on the quality of code of the module). However, this is not helpful for me as I have no idea where my problem is in the v1 module.

Does anyone know how to turn on errors/exceptions for modules? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like its doing its job just fine. Are you sure your v1 is returning the right value? or printing out the value that v1 is returning in server.js? because its not going to automatically print out the returned value, you still have to put it in a console.log(v1()); or something similar. without knowing what v1 actually returns, its hard to say what is suppose to be printed.